# Mindstorms EV3 PC application won't load

Tags: mindstorms

Installed Mindstorms EV3 application on MS Windows 7 Home Premium v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) and I keep getting the same error message when launching.

A white window pops up with the following:

LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 has detected a problem during application launch. Press OK to close the application and get more information about fixing the problem.

There is only a single "OK" button to press and it then launches the web browser to a lego page link which cannot be found.

I have checked with Lego tech support and they suggested the issue was with MS Silverlight which I un-installed and re-installed along with the EV3 application... all to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: To my surprise, re-installing Silverlight did resolve the issue for me on .Windows 10)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with windows 10.  Installing the latest silverlight from here: https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx did the trick

Comment: This also works for fixing Mac OSX

Answer (score 0):

Try this guide I found in the LEGO Education Website:  https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/mindstorms-ev3/software-launch-issues

Answer (score 0):

If the program opens but loading appears the whole time, just open a new program and save it... and open it again, it will work.

This is a glitch.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Exit the application then remove the folder
C:\Users\LegoLeague\AppData\Local\LEGO\MINDSTORMS EV3
Then restart the EV3 Mindstorm application